# Difference between .text() in d3js and jQuery when using jQuery.dotdotdot

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I have struggled with using [jquery.dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) with [d3js](http://d3js.org/). The problem I had was that after I added `dotdotdot` to the text object I could not update the text by `d3.select(...).text("new text)`. Take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aqUNjNyJlV5vaLMk8NDi?p=preview).

I found out that if I used jQuery to replace the text it worked just fine. My question is therefor what the difference is. Why does it work when done this way?

```
text.select("span")
    //.text(d.data.label) <=== problem
    .each(function(d){
        $(this).text(d.data.label); <=== solution (?)
    });
```

Comment: I think you are getting your selections wrong perhaps.  What is the first `text` derived from here? https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

Comment: It is from this... `var text = d3.select(this).select("div.label-wrapper").selectAll("div.chart-label").data(pie(was), key);`. The text is updated by d3, but dotdotdot doesn't know about it. If I reinitialize dotdotdot immediately after d3 has updated the text it is reset to the original text dotdotdot saw when it was first initialized.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at triggering the update event of dotdotdot seen at bottom of page you referenced.